# why when I´m using fileupload in primefaces I can do ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsf-2, primefaces

I´ve an uploader that appears inside a dialog. So when I upload my file with success; I want my dialgo to close and if I got an error after the upload I don´t want to close my dialog. So my upload works but when it´s time to close my dialog I get the message from firebur: ReferenceError: args is not defined.
Here is the code for my dialog:

```
<p:dialog maximizable="true" 
          minHeight="400" 
          minWidth="400" 
          id="dialogCarga" 
          header="Cargar gestores" 
          widgetVar="gestorCargarDialog" 
          resizable="false"
          modal="true">
    <p:ajax event="close" 
            listener="#{gestorMB.handleClose}" 
            update="agregarGestor"/>
    <h:form id="cargarGestor">
        <p:growl id="growl2" 
                 showDetail="false" />
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
            <h:outputText id="layoutUpd" 
                          value="Subir archivo:" />
            </td>                                               
            <td align="left">
            <p:fileUpload invalidSizeMessage="El archivo tiene un tama&ntilde;o superior al v&aacute;lido" 
                          label="Escoger" cancelLabel="Cancelar" 
                          uploadLabel="Cargar archivo" 
                          fileUploadListener="#{gestorMB.handleFileUpload}"
                          id="SigUPD" 
                          oncomplete="handleCargarGestRequest(args)" 
                          invalidFileMessage="Tipo de archivo inv&aacute;lido, solo se aceptan archivos con extensi&oacute;n csv." process="@this"
                          allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv)$/" sizeLimit="20971520" 
                          update=":gestorForm:, erroresCarga, growl2, SigUPD" 
                          fileLimit="1" 
                          fileLimitMessage="Favor de cargar un archivo a la vez.">                                    
            </p:fileUpload>
            </td>                                                  
            </tr> 
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
            <p:outputPanel id="layoutGestores">
                <a href="#{gestorMB.layoutLinkGestores}" 
                   target="_blank">Descargar formato de carga de gestores.</a> 
            </p:outputPanel>
            * Nota: Todos los campos del archivo son obligatorios menos la extensi&oacute;n.
            El archivo debe estar libre de errores para poder cargar los gestores.
            </td>                              
            </tr>
        </table>
        <p:dataTable id="erroresCarga" 
                     value="#{gestorMB.msgError}" 
                     var="element" 
                     paginator="true" 
                     rows="10" 
                     emptyMessage="No existen errores"
                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} 
                                        {FirstPageLink} 
                                        {PreviousPageLink} 
                                        {PageLinks} 
                                        {NextPageLink} 
                                        {LastPageLink} 
                                        {RowsPerPageDropdown}"  
                     rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,40" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                Errores en el archivo #{gestorMB.nombreArchivo}
            </f:facet>      
            <p:column headerText="Error">
                #{element}
            </p:column>                                                    
        </p:dataTable>                       
    </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

and here is the code that I use from fileupload method to close the dialog:
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().addCallbackParam(Constantes.EXITO2, Constantes.TRUE);

and finally here is my js where I close the dialog:

```
function handleCargarGestRequest(args) {
    alert("handleCargarGestRequest: " + args.exito);
    if (args.exito) {
        gestorCargarDialog.hide();
    } else {
        gestorCargarDialog.show();
    }
}
```

I already try using handleCargarGestRequest(xhr, status, args), and it doesn´t work. I get that xhr is not defined.
Does anyone knows why I can close the dialog after finishing the upload??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I *think* you can do (with PF 4 and newer syntax)

```
oncomplete="if(args &amp;&amp; !args.validationFailed) {PF('gestorCargarDialog').hide();}"
```

and on the bean (in case of error)

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Errormessage..."));
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().validationFailed();
```